# Why the template_preprocess_field hook is not called for a custom template?

Tags: 7, hooks, theming

I'm working in a site that has implemented the [template_preprocess_field()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21field%21field.module/function/template_preprocess_field/7.x) hook. I want to change the content of a field but the code works for all the nodes except for the nodes of a content type that have a custom template (`node--emploi.tpl.php`) It's strange because I have another template for the nodes of the content type named tarif (`node--tarif.tpl.php`) and in this case the hook is called.

Here the piece of code inside the template node--emploi.tpl.php file:

```
<div class="editor">
  <?php
  /* At this point the body's h2 do not know what the nid is, so a quick and dirty replace will set it right. */
  print preg_replace('/NO-NID[a-z0-9]*--/', $nid . '--', check_markup($field_stm_emploi_temoignage_body[0]['value'], $field_stm_emploi_temoignage_body[0]['format']));
 ?>
</div>
```

Comment: ...and the field is 100% definitely being rendered as normal in node--emploi.tpl.php? With the same field formatter as is working for other node types? Can you post the code? I suspect you've changed `print render($content['field_foo']);` to print `$content['field_foo']` or some derivative, meaning it's not being rendered through the theme system. Would need to see the template to make sure of course

Comment: @Clive Yes you have reason, I test the template with `print render($content['field_foo']);` and its works fine. Please post your answer to check it as accepted ;-)

Comment: Sorry, missed your comment somehow. Looks like you took care of it!

Comment: @Clive yes I write the answer as guide for other users, but If you want post another answer with more examples or info and I can check it as accepted. You have more experience in this field.

Comment: Honestly, I think your answer covers it. There are other more advanced solutions (e.g. custom field formatter), but they're probably overly complicated for this

Comment: @Clive can you provide me a good link to read about the custom field formatter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [@Clive](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/207578/why-the-template-preprocess-field-hook-is-not-called-for-a-custom-template#comment252959_207578) says the problem was that the code didn't use the `render()` function for the field output, and in this case the [template_preprocess_field()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21field%21field.module/function/template_preprocess_field/7.x) hook is not called.

For the moment I have 2 solutions:

1. Use the [render()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/render/7.x) function in the template file (node--emploi.tpl.php) to create the output of the field. In this case the [template_preprocess_field()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21field%21field.module/function/template_preprocess_field/7.x) hook is called.
2. Use the [template_preprocess_node()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.module/function/template_preprocess_node/7.x) hook and check `$vars['type']` for my content type. In this case the template file remains equal.